# Passing creds to gitlab-ci runner to be able to push docker image…?

Tags: gitlab-ci-runner

I'm setting up a gitlab-ci process, but I'm having trouble understanding how I should manage my secrets…

So I have successfully started up a gitlab/gitlab-runner as a docker container and registered a docker runner from gitlab/dind.

The thing I want to build in this case is simply building a docker image from a Dockerfile, populating caches to later be used by other ci integration test builds. This by pushing it up to my private docker registry. My .gitlab-ci.yml definition in this case is just:

```
build_image:
  script:
    - docker build -t ensime/ensime-atom-ci .
    - docker tag ensime/ensime-atom-ci docker.woodenstake.se/ensime/ensime-atom-ci
    - docker push docker.woodenstake.se/ensime/ensime-atom-ci
```

Seems simple enough, but of course I have no creds here so it fails:

I just came from drone where I generated a .sec file for this.

But here I should login, right? So I've read here

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/blob/master/docs/configuration/advanced-configuration.md#using-a-private-docker-registry

Problem is since I'm running gitlab-runner from within the dockerized gitlab/gitlab-runner image, there doesn't even seem to be a docker cli there?

```
viktor@i7:/var/lib$ sudo docker exec -it gitlab-runner docker login
exec: "docker": executable file not found in $PATH
```

Any tips highly appreciated!

Update for clarification:

So the tail of the gitlab-ci build log is:

```
012ca7ed9b62: Retrying in 1 seconds
173cd98367a6: Retrying in 1 seconds
92b0661193a5: Retrying in 1 seconds
c12ecfd4861d: Waiting
5f70bf18a086: Retrying in 5 seconds
no basic auth credentials

ERROR: Build failed: exit code 1
```

The host machine is logged in the registry as root. Trying to login from the docker container I just don't even have docker cli.

I have added the `--docker-privileged` flag on the registration of the runner.

I guess the credentials needs to pass through host -> gitlab-runner -> runner instance (dind)

Comment: Did you figure out how to log on? I'm currently facing the same issue...

Answer (score 7):

If you are using GitLab's own container registry you have to add the following to the script section on your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

`docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p "${CI_BUILD_TOKEN:-$CI_JOB_TOKEN}" docker.woodenstake.se`

If you are using an external registry, I suggest you add the credentials as variables to your build on Project Settings > Variables, then you can add the line `docker login -u "$USER_VAR" -p "$PASS_VAR" docker.woodenstake.se` to the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file.

It should look like this:

```
build_image:
  script:
    - 'docker login -u "$USER_VAR" -p "$PASS_VAR" docker.woodenstake.se'
    - docker build -t ensime/ensime-atom-ci .
    - docker tag ensime/ensime-atom-ci docker.woodenstake.se/ensime/ensime-atom-ci
    - docker push docker.woodenstake.se/ensime/ensime-atom-ci
```

Answer (score 1):

To use images from a private registry the runner needs to have the credentials. As you found out yourself, the gitlab/gitlab-runner image does not have the `docker` command available.
The simplest solution is to login to your registry from the host where the runner is running on:

```
docker login your.registry:5000
```

After that, mount `~/.docker/config.json` as `/root/.docker/config.json` in your gitlab-runner instance.

To push images during your build refer to Eduardo Cardoso's answer.